# Persistent storage for React Native Webview

Tags: react-native, local-storage

I'm trying to use local storage in Webview with React Native.
I've noticed it gets wiped when unmounting the component containing the Webview.

Is there a way to keep it around?
Or would a better solution be to retrieve the values, pass it to AsyncStorage?

Comment: @Naota Ida Did you manage to figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing myself

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use [react-native-webview-bridge](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge) to seed an AsyncStorage storage, you can either way retrieve and set values in a webview with it

Comment: [react-native-webview-messaging](https://github.com/R1ZZU/react-native-webview-messaging) is an alternative package for RN<=>webview communication